# Ubuntu 19.10 - New laptop - inconsistent behavious - install all drivers?

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I just bought a new laptop (Lenovo C640). I installed Ubuntu. I have one problem in particular that is quite frustrating:

the touchpad sometimes doesn't work. I boot ubuntu, and sometimes, the cursor stays still in the down-right corner of the screen. This is quite a random behaviour, as other times it works correctly.

I installed the xorg-input-synaptics driver, but didn't change anything.

Question A: any idea on how to solve this problem? The "xinput list" command reports a 'MSFT002121:00 06CB:CDB0 Touchpad".

Question 2: instead of waiting to discover new problems here and there, how can I install now all the drivers needed for my hardware to work? Is there any default method to make sure things are correctly set up?

Comment: There is no "default" driver "for everything".

Comment: I mean a default method, like "look at all the hardware you have with this command" and then "make sure you have all the drivers installed for those". If you don't, install...

Comment: This is always done. Linux kernel does that on every boot. But that doesn't mean that each and every piece of hardware is perfectly supported out of the box.

Comment: Ok, any idea on how to solve the problem with the touchpad? How can I track down the problem and solve it?

Comment: I don't have a solution. And it is possible that there is no easy solution.

Comment: I tried to install the Gestures application, and I get the error: "Can not see any devices, did you add yourself to the input group and log out/in?
Could not determine touchpad device." . This is a good hint. What do you think it is happening?

Comment: I think this touchpad is not supported by Linux yet.

Comment: Great! Very good to know! Thanks Pilot6!